# Draw own (non existent) public transport for TravelTime plugin analysis

Tags: qgis, service-area

Is it possible to draw my own transit lines (for eg. a new rail line) which does not exist but I want to analyse for example service areas if a new particular line would be built?

Example in the 'screenshot 1' below, I want to add a new rail line (purple line) and assign schedule on my own. After that I want to do a traveltime analysis (using TravelTime plugin) as shown in the 'screenshot 2'.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: This is not possible without any background, raster or vector. You have to make at least some network of points according to importance and then connect them with some algorithm.